# How to mass refresh textures and say blender to look for them at different location

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, texturing

While working on a blender scene i have to move it from a usual place on hard drive to a different location. After i made some changes in scene and brought it back to its usual place all texture files are pointing in the wrong directory and are missing. There are hundreds textures in the scene and i cant reassign them by hand, it there a way to make all nodes that reffer to textures to look for them in a different directory?

What i have now is:
Blender looking for hundreds of textures in: wrong_folder/no_textures/
But i want them to look for textures in: right_folder/textures/

Something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can  do that using python script to alter the path of every image located in the older folder to be looked for in the new one; the nodes will automatically be updated after this :

```
import bpy

images = bpy.data.images  

for img in images :
    if img.source == 'FILE' :
         img.filepath = img.filepath.replace('\\old_folder\\','\\new_folder\\')
         img.reload()
```